# mysql_query SELECT statement in php stops returning results after a while?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I have made a program that continuously processes tweets and categorizes them into different archives.

For that I have a php script that continuously loops (WHILE TRUE) and checks if new tweets have arrived in the database. It therefore also selects all possible archives a tweet can belong to:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id from archives", $db->connection);
```

Where $db->connection is

```
class MySQLDB
{
 var $connection;      

 function MySQLDB(){
      $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
   }

}
$db = new MySQLDB;
```

This is were the problem lies. This fetching of archives works well but after some time (two to three days) it stops returning results. the mysql select statement does not return any results but does not give an error. Is this a problem someone of you already encountered? Can anyone give hints on what could be the issue here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I understand you, once in a while your program runs the query to fetch the `id` values from the `archive` table, and after some amount of time the query starts returning an empty result set. Is that correct? Are you checking for errors when you run the query?

Comment: Do you disconnect and reconnect to the database each time you do the query? I would expect a simple query like that to be very fast, hence likely putting it into a loop could result in it being performed many times per second (possibly hundreds). Over 3 days at 100 times a second that is ~25 million queries.

Comment: @ollie-jones That is correct. For some kind of reason the query stops returning results after a while. Indeed the number of the times the query is executed is huge but that should not be a problem I think? I print mysql_error() if it's different from an empty string. The only thing I can think of is that it is somehow related to the database connection. The class MySQLDB (see above) is located in a separate config.php file and then included in the php script. (because the database is used by other php scripts as well).

Comment: The strange thing is that this general select query (select * from archives) does not return any result but other mysql queries remain functional as they should.

Comment: I would be inclined to disconnect and reconnect the database connection occasionally and see if this fixes it. Possible that it is some obscure error from it recording the number of times a query is executed (for caching maybe) and over flowing a count. With luck this reconnecting will reset things.

Comment: Seems like a plausible explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you check what does `mysql_query` return?

maybe instead of an empty result set it returns 'false' for error?

try

```
mysql_query() or die('error:'. mysql_error());
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

my guess is that after running for so long, the ammount of records to fetch from the database is too big. Do you remove the records you already read?